# How do we change to dark theme UI in kate editor on ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, unity, kde, themes, kate

I recently moved to kate editor and so far loving it. I love dark themes and I am using this as my system wide default. Now I want to change the kate's ui to dark theme too. But sofar I am only able to change the editors color schema alone by **settings > Configure Kate > Editor Component > Fonts & Colour scheme**.

[image]

How can we change to dark theme UI in kate editor on ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 8):

I was earlier using an old version of kate and then I upgraded to the latest version of kate. After upgrading I installed `breeze` using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y breeze
```

After installing breeze, went to `Settings > Color Scheme > Breeze Dark`. This changed the UI to dark theme.

Comment: `Note:` I had to close Kate and reopen it before I could see the breeze color schemes installed above. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.