# In kwrite, how do you change the UI theme to dark mode?

Tags: themes

In Kwrite, the default theme is light, making the UI look like this:

[image: Kwrite using the light theme]
See also the related (but distinctly different) question [How do we change to dark theme UI in kate editor on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339937/how-do-we-change-to-dark-theme-ui-in-kate-editor-on-ubuntu).

How can I make it use the dark theme? If I go into the settings → configure kwrite → colour theme, it only changes the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, the option to configure this is in the context menu, not the actual settings.

Go to the 3 lines at the top right, then go to settings → window colour theme → breeze dark.

This will change the UI theme to dark:

[image: Kwrite using the dark theme]